# How to convert list of lists in tuple to list of lists in python?

Tags: python, tuples

I have this as output:

```
L = ([['AAA', '193.0', 'GGG']], [['BBB', '196.33333333333334', 'TTT']], 
[['CCC', '18.666666666666668', 'AAA']])
```

I want it to be converted to a list of lists like:

```
L = [['AAA', '193.0', 'GGG'], ['BBB', '196.33333333333334', 'TTT'], 
['CCC', '18.666666666666668', 'AAA']]
```

I have tried to use

```
L = list(L)
```

and

```
[list(elem) for elem in L]
```

and

```
L = map(list, L)
```

But I cannot get any of them to work. 
Can someone please help me out?

Comment: What is your initial data?

Answer (score 3):

You could use any of these:

1. `list(zip(*L)[0])`
2. `[item for subitem in L for item in subitem]`
3. `list(itertools.chain(*L))`
4. `functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, L)`

---

#### First solution

```
list(zip(*L)[0])
```

First solution converts resulting `tuple` in `list`, just like you wanted. But if result is just used for reading, you do not need a `list`. `tuple` will be just fine.

---

#### Second solution

```
[item for subitem in L for item in subitem]
```

Second case will flatten even this:

```
L = ([['AAA', '193.0', 'GGG'], ['AAA', '193.0', 'GGG']], [['BBB', '196.33333333333334', 'TTT']], [['CCC', '18.666666666666668', 'AAA']])
```

to

```
[['AAA', '193.0', 'GGG'],
 ['AAA', '193.0', 'GGG'],
 ['BBB', '196.33333333333334', 'TTT'],
 ['CCC', '18.666666666666668', 'AAA']]
```

---

#### Third solution

```
list(itertools.chain(*L))
```

Third solution is even prettier. What it does it goes through a list of iterables and returns each iterable's elements.

#### Fourth solution

```
functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, L)
```

This solution is just to show how else you can accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

you have a list of lists inside your tuple, but each list contains one element.

Rebuild the list using a list comprehension, taking the one and only element of the list:

```
L = ([['AAA', '193.0', 'GGG']], [['BBB', '196.33333333333334', 'TTT']],
[['CCC', '18.666666666666668', 'AAA']])

L = [x[0] for x in L]

print(L)
```

result:

```
[['AAA', '193.0', 'GGG'], ['BBB', '196.33333333333334', 'TTT'], ['CCC', '18.666666666666668', 'AAA']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is flawed. You have a tuple of single-element lists containing lists, and you just want a list of lists. So you need to extract the first element of each list:

```
L = [elem[0] for elem in L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy's squeeze removes extra dimensions from lists and tuples.

```
   from numpy import squeeze
    L = squeeze(L).tolist()
```

Comment: ohh seems a different try. Its new to me. pretty cool and good answer.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using `map`, typical use `map(function, iterable)`

In python 2.7 map returns a list of the result of applying the function to each item in the iterable. so we can use

```
L = map(lambda l:l[0],L)
```

In python 3.x map returns an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable(this is the tuple in our case), yielding the results, so list will be required to convert the resulting iterator to a list. i.e.

```
L = list(map(lambda l:l[0],L))
```

In either cases, the output of `print(L)` will be

```
[['AAA', '193.0', 'GGG'],
 ['BBB', '196.33333333333334', 'TTT'],
 ['CCC', '18.666666666666668', 'AAA']]
```

The function `lambda l: l[0]` is an anonymous function that takes a list and return the first element in it. in other words it squeezes the list elements of the tuple.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.